# How do you automatically add text dynamically to an image an export it?

Tags: reactjs, image, user-interface, image-processing, data-processing

Recently, Spotify released their 2019 Spotify wrapped web application, which is essentially a way for both music artists and music listeners to rewind and review what they listened to/who listened to their music in the past year.

As part of their site, they dynamically created these images that people could either export or share to one of their social media networks.

[image: Example of dynamically generated image from Spotify]

Above is an example of one of those dynamically generated images (of course, the image, and the text/statistics below change).

How would I go about doing this in code?

Sorry if this is in the wrong place - just wasn't sure where I would post this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this would be to use a SVG as your base template allowing you to add in the text values after the fact.

Add the SVG to a canvas which can then be converted to jpeg by using `.toDataURL("image/jpeg")`